# Download local file to new folder? as3

Tags: actionscript-3, file, download, location, new-operator

I've searched for hours no luck. I'm new to as3 and i can't figure this out.

I have a swf and i want to click a button and for it to open a "save as" box (or something similar) and save a designated file to a location of my choice.

Basically it would be creating a copy of this file to a new location.

If anyone could help my I'd love to hear it!!!

Kind Regards,
Jack

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.net.FileReference;
var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
fr.save(yourByteArray, fileName);
```

this will open "save as" box .

Comment: what is the 'yourByteArray'? sorry

Comment: flash.utils.ByteArray , if You like to save file from SWF You need to have it on bytes and for this You have to use ByteArray